# Limit decimal points

Tags: r

I have a result of a R command in the form of Odds ratio with Credible limits generated between multiple items. The result of a single comparison is like '0.565866331549561 (0.13888341792753, 2.28200586479249)' and there are multiple such comparisons.
I have saved the output as a CSV file.
I want the output to be limited to 2 decimal places but all the commands which have tried are converting this output to 0.56 and removing the Credible limits.
I have tried
sprintf(df, fmt = '%#.2f')

options(digits = 2)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `round` to get just 2 decimal.

```
round(x, digits = 2)
```

Comment: This is  a sample ```round(143.1234, digits = 2)
[1] 143.12```